# How to access a property of an object in an array and sort an array by it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a task - I need to sort an array of objects by their property. The property is inserted by the user (as well as all the objects) and then they should be sorted by the key, which should be equal to a parameter name. 
I insert all the data and it doesn't do what it should. Please help me find a solution.

```
   var employees = [];
   function Employee (name, sName, age, occupation) {
       this.name = name; 
       this.sName = sName;
       this.age = age; 
       this.occupation = occupation;
       this.show = function () {
            console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.sName + ' is ' 
            + this.age + ' years old, ' + 'and he/she is a ' + this.occupation);
       }
   } 



   function createNewEmployee () {
        var anotherEmployee; 

        for (i = 0; i < Infinity; i++) {
            var newEmployee = new Employee (prompt('First Name: '), prompt('Last Name: '), +prompt('Age: '),
            prompt('Job title(occupation): '));
            if (isNaN(newEmployee.age)) {
                alert('Age is a number! Try again!');
            } else {
                employees.push(newEmployee);
            }
            anotherEmployee = prompt('Add another employee? (y/n)');
            if (anotherEmployee == 'n') { 
                for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
                    employees[i].show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
   }

   createNewEmployee();

   // 4 

   function addSalary (employees) {

       for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            switch (employees[i].occupation) {
                case 'director': 
                    employees[i].salary = 3000;
                    break;
                case 'manager': 
                    employees[i].salary = 1500;
                    break;
                case 'programmer': 
                    employees[i].salary = 2000;
                    break;
                default: 
                    employees[i].salary = 1000;
                    break;
            }
       }
       for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            employees[i].show = function () {
                console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.sName + ' is ' 
            + this.age + ' years old, ' + 'and he/she is a ' + this.occupation + '.' + ' ' + 'His/Her salary is ' + this.salary + '$');
            }
            employees[i].show();
        }
   }

   addSalary(employees);


// 5  

function employeeSorting () {
    var sortedElement = prompt('What parameter should be used for sorting? (options: name, sName, age, occupation, salary)');
    if (sortedElement in employees)
        {
            if (typeof(sortedElement) == 'string') {
            function compareString (a, b) {
                var nameA = a[sortedElement].toUpperCase();
                var nameB = b[sortedElement].toUpperCase();
                if (nameA > nameB) return 1;
                if (nameA < nameB) return -1;
                return 0;
            }
            employees.sort(compareString);
            return (employees);
        } else {
            function compareNumber (a, b) {
                if (a[sortedElement] < b[sortedElement]) return 1;
                if (a[sortedElement] > b[sortedElement]) return -1;
                return 0;
            }
            employees.sort(compareNumber);
            return (employees);
            }
        } else {
        alert('You have entered an invalid parameter, please try again');
        var sortedElement = prompt('What parameter should be used for sorting? (options: name, sName, age, occupation, salary)');
    }
} 

employeeSorting(employees);

employees.forEach(function(element) {
    element.show();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach you can take that should get you started. This is a function that sorts objects with your defined properties and accepts a property name to sort by (only handles integers and strings currently):

```js
let data = [{ name: 'John', sName: 'Foo', age: 20, occupation: 'Developer', salary: 40000 },{ name: 'Bob', sName: 'Boo', age: 40, occupation: 'Chef', salary: 20000 },{ name: 'Mark', sName: 'Yu', age: 50, occupation: 'Manager', salary: 50000 }]

let sortBy = (arr, prop) => arr.sort((a,b) => Number.isInteger(a[prop])
  ? (a[prop] - b[prop])
  : a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop])
)

console.log(sortBy(data, 'age'))
console.log(sortBy(data, 'name'))
console.log(sortBy(data, 'occupation'))
console.log(sortBy(data, 'salary'))
```

So your `employeeSorting` function would be something like this:

```
function employeeSorting () {
  var sortedElement = prompt('What parameter should be used for sorting? (options: name, sName, age, occupation, salary)');
  if (sortedElement in employees)
    return sortBy(employees, sortedElement) // <-- use sortBy here 
  else
    alert('You have entered an invalid parameter, please try again');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your sorting function. For example, you're checking if a property name exists in an array of objects like this: `sortedElement in employees`. It will not work. You need to iterate over this array, then get all object keys of the given array entry and check whether they include the provided property or not.

I've rewritten this function from scratch. It works as it's supposed to and can be directly replaced without any changes to other parts of your code:

```
function employeeSorting() {
    const sortedElement = prompt('What parameter should be used for sorting? (options: name, sName, age, occupation, salary)');
    try {
        employees = employees.sort((employee1, employee2) => { //Overwrites the global employees array
            const val1 = employee1[sortedElement];
            const val2 = employee2[sortedElement];
            if (val1 === undefined || val2 === undefined) { //If a non-existing property was entered, throw an error
                throw ('You have entered an invalid parameter, please try again');
            }
            if (!isNaN(val1) && !isNaN(val2)){ //Check numbers
                return parseInt(val1) < parseInt(val2) ? -1 : parseInt(val1) > parseInt(val2) ? 1 : 0;
            } else if (typeof val1 === 'string' && typeof val2 === 'string'){ //Check strings
                return val1.toUpperCase() < val2.toUpperCase() ? -1 : val1.toUpperCase() > val2.toUpperCase() ? 1 : 0;
            } else { //Both properties had different types
                throw('There\'s a data type inconsistency between employees');
            }
        });
    } catch (error) { //Ask for the correct property name again if an error was thrown
        alert(error);
        return employeeSorting();
    }
}
```